# MSSQL filter row in replication limits

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication, database-administration, transactional-replication

I have a transactional replication between two databases where I filter rows because I just want to replicate rows with certain userids. I have now hit the roof when it seems that the filters can’t contain any more characters. Is this a known limit?

Does anyone have any idea how this scenario is solvable? (I have considered merge transaction with table join but do to multiple ETL processes I can’t add the required unique column required)

Comment: Have your tried adding a computed column to the source table?  Or adding a static table in the source DB with the UserId then using a UDF in the Parametrized filter?  Might get more joy on DBA though.  Join filter looks doable though

Comment: I have all userids that should be replicated in a table. I didn't think of the UDF approach. Maybe I could try that.